# error message on fbx export

Tags: export, .fbx

I am getting this error message on export. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 636, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1163, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    uvlayer.data.foreach_get("uv", t_luv)
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T87038

Comment: Seems to be something about UV data being out of date. Try selecting your mesh, and toggling in an out of edit mode. You'll have to do it for all your meshes since you don't know which one is messed up.